# Lotus notes view excludes replied to mail

Tags: email, lotus-notes, lotusscript, lotus-formula

Is it possible to create a view in lotus notes that only displays the original email, not the replied to ones?

e.g. we get our work submitted to us through email and i'm trying to create a view that shows us everything we have to do - but when we reply to an email, it creates another document in the list...skewing the figures.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to selection formula in view

```
SELECT ... & Form != "Reply"
```

or *deselect* view property

```
Show response documents in hierarchy
```

depending on how your view is build.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer:

> SELECT (@Created > [01/01/2014]) & (@IsNotMember("A"; ExcludeFromView) & IsMailStationery != 1 & Form != "Group" & Form != "Person" ) & !( DeliveredDate = "" & PostedDate != "" & !(@IsMember("S"; ExcludeFromView)) )

This does not display Sent Mail :)